# web exception while calling ClientContext.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate() in sharepoint provision from a template

Tags: sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I am using the folllowing approach to provision a sharepoint site from a template:

```
ClientContext.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate, provisioningTemplateApplyingInformation);
```

this was working correctly and suddenly it starts to give me an exception while it tries to provision from the template. is suspect it could be related to OfficeDevPnP.dll

```
the full error is as shown below.
[Fields]    [4] [Error] Updating field {32454-fafg-691d-9387-6342c27538} failed: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. :    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryToServerAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.<ExecuteQueryImplementation>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.<ExecuteQueryImplementation>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay, String userAgent)
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectField.UpdateField(Web web, String fieldId, XElement templateFieldElement, PnPMonitoredScope scope, TokenParser parser, String originalFieldXml)
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectField.ProvisionObjects(Web web, ProvisioningTemplate template, TokenParser parser, ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation applyingInformation)
```

and sometimes it also give me the following error. but the error is on the the same call which is:
ClientContext.Web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate, provisioningTemplateApplyingInformation);

```
func.exe Error: 0 : 2021-04-23 18:22:44.7701    [OfficeDevPnP.Core] [0] [Error] ExecuteQuery threw following exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryToServerAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.<ExecuteQueryImplementation>d__7.MoveNext().  0ms 
func.exe Information: 0 : 2021-04-23 18:22:44.7741  [Content Types] [4] [Debug] Code execution scope ended  18482ms 
func.exe Information: 0 : 2021-04-23 18:22:44.7761  [ProvisioningTemplate WebHook Call] [4] [Debug] Code execution scope started    0ms
func.exe Information: 0 : 2021-04-23 18:22:44.7781  [ProvisioningTemplate WebHook Call] [4] [Debug] Code execution scope ended  1ms
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll
```

my package version for SharePointPnPCoreOnline is:

and, target framework i am using is .NET Framwork 4.6.1

I am wondering if there is a recent feature update done on OfficeDevPnP.dll that can cause this issue.

Thank you in advance!